# Samsung NP355V4C optical drive completely disconnected

Tags: windows-7, bios, optical-drive, eject, cd-drive

This laptop is less than a year old.  It runs Windows 7.  Today I found I could not open the DVD drive by pressing the eject button on it.  It does not show up in My Computer.  I found [the manual](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201210/20121026203157153/Win8_Manual_eng.pdf) which on page 49 shows how to manually eject using a paper clip.  I did that, but when I put in a disc, I do not hear it spool up like normal, and nothing appears in My Computer.  That is when I found that the drive does not appear in Device Manager, either.  I rebooted and found that even the BIOS does not mention it anywhere anymore.

I wanted to see if I could unplug and replug the drive, and the manual mentions disassembling in the safety introduction, but does not go into much detail about which sequence it should be disassembled in.  Is there a safe way to try this or should I take my chances trying to get warranty service at Future Shop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the optical drive is just dead.

If you don't know how to disassemble it properly, and/or are uncomfortable, then yes you should take it to someone who knows what they are doing.

Also, if the system is still under warranty and you mess it up while disassembling it, you void your warranty.

If you don't trust Future Shop, contact your notebook manufacturer and find a registered local repair depot that isn't a Future Shop. :)